# Как добавить новые строки в таблицу БД программно, в eXpressapp Framework

Tags: c#, devexpress

Использую C#. Создал несколько бизнес классов. Стоит задача загрузить данные из другой БД(выборочно) в свою. Так вот как это сделать, читал мануалки, про это вообще ничего нет, на саппорт дал вопрос, не отвечают. Как создать еще одно подключение к другой БД помимо уже существующей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем оказалось все просто, достаточно создать экземпляр бизнес-объекта, занести в него нужную информацию, и сохранить в сессии или в пространстве объектов, в зависимости от области видимости:

- 1вар.Session.Save(newobj);
- 2вар.ObjectSpace(newobj);

Не забыть произвести сохранение изменений методом  CommitTransaction() или CommitChange() соответственно.